# Why the position of the next() instruction change the behavior of my application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I followed the [Keystone documentation](https://keystonejs.com/getting-started/yo-generator/) for creating a new project. 
I'm trying to create a page that behaves differently based on whether the user is logged in or not.

My pug page it's something like that:

```
extends ../layouts/default

block content
    if(!user)
        .container: .jumbotron
            .row
                .col-md-2
                .col-md-8.text-center.welcome
                    h2 Welcome
                .col-md-2
    else
        .container: .jumbotron
            .row
                .col-md-2
                .col-md-8.text-center.welcome
                    h2 Logged in
                .col-md-2
            .row
```

My index.js have this at the end, for expose the endpoints:

```
// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    // Views
    app.get('/', routes.views.index);
    app.all('/signin', routes.views.signin);
};
```

And the JavaScript file that serve the routing `signin` endpoint is:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var User = keystone.list('User');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;
    var utente = req.body.utente;
    var passwd = req.body.password;

    // locals.section is used to set the currently selected
    // item in the header navigation.
    locals.section = 'home';

    view.on('init', function(next){
        next();
    });

    view.on('post', { action: 'signin' }, function (next) {
        // console.log("utente: " + utente);

        User.model.find()
            .where('email', utente)
            .exec()
            .then(function (user) { //first promise fulfilled
                //return another async promise

                console.log("user: ", user);
                console.log("email: ", user[0].email);
                console.log("password: ", user[0].password);

                bcrypt.compare(passwd, user[0].password, function(err, res) {
                    if(res){
                        console.log("Signin OK!");
                        locals.user = user[0];
                    }else{
                        console.log("Wrong Email or Password!");
                        req.flash("error", "wrong email or password!");
                    }
                });

            }, function (err) { //something happened
                //catch the error, it can be thrown by any promise in the chain
                console.log(err);
            });

        next();
    });

    // Render the view
    view.render('index');
};
```

But my pug page doesn't recognize the `user` variable, how it should be.

Instead if I move the `next()` instruction more internally:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var User = keystone.list('User');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;
    var utente = req.body.utente;
    var passwd = req.body.password;

    // locals.section is used to set the currently selected
    // item in the header navigation.
    locals.section = 'home';

    view.on('init', function(next){
        next();
    });

    view.on('post', { action: 'signin' }, function (next) {
        // console.log("utente: " + utente);

        User.model.find()
            .where('email', utente)
            .exec()
            .then(function (user) { //first promise fulfilled
                //return another async promise

                console.log("user: ", user);
                console.log("email: ", user[0].email);
                console.log("password: ", user[0].password);

                bcrypt.compare(passwd, user[0].password, function(err, res) {
                    if(res){
                        console.log("Signin OK!");
                        locals.user = user[0];
                    }else{
                        console.log("Wrong Email or Password!");
                        req.flash("error", "wrong email or password!");
                    }
                    next();
                });

            }, function (err) { //something happened
                //catch the error, it can be thrown by any promise in the chain
                console.log(err);
                next();
            });

        //next();
    });

    // Render the view
    view.render('index');
};
```

Everything goes fine! And the `user` variable is read correctly.

How it is possible? In these two pieces of code the position of the `next()` function isn't equivalent???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're definitely not equivalent. You have

```
        aPromise
            .then(function (user) { //first promise fulfilled
                bcrypt.compare(passwd, user[0].password, function(err, res) {/*...*/});

        next();
```

vs

```
        aPromise
            .then(function (user) { //first promise fulfilled
                bcrypt.compare(passwd, user[0].password, function(err, res) {
                    /*...*/
                    next();
                });
```

In your first one, `next()` is executed before the promise is fulfilled, passwords compared, callback called, and `locals.user` assigned a value. In your second one, it's executed *after* all of that has happened.

Comment: But if it's executed after all of that has happened, shouldn't I see the `user` variable anyway (first case) since it was assigned?

Comment: In first case, `next()` is executed when `user` is still undefined.

Comment: Is it for the asynchronous behavior of the promises?

Comment: Both. Even with no true async action of any kind, this: `Promise.resolve('foo').then(console.log); console.log('bar');` will log 'bar' first, 'foo' second.